# Spring Boot and Kotlin - How to validate a JSON object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm using Spring Boot in Kotlin.

I'm taking in some JSON string, parsing it with ObjectMapper however I want to validate it has everything as in per the model - namely `id` and `s3FilePath` are not blank or missing.

So this is the model I want to validate against:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class MyModel {
    var id : String = ""
    var s3FilePath : String = ""
}
```

This is where I use that model:

```
class FirstMessage {
    fun create(newMessage: String) : String {

        val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
        val parsedMap : MyModel = objectMapper.readValue(newMessage, MyModel::class.java)

        val result = MyModel()
        result.id = parsedMap.id
        result.s3FilePath = parsedMap.s3FilePath

        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(result)
    }
}
```

And finally I have this test where I want to validate an exception:

```
@Test
    fun incompleteDataReturnsException() {
        var input = """{"missing": "parts"}"""

        // FirstMessage().create(input) // Will make some assertion here here
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've just started using Spring and its pretty 'intense'.

Thanks.

p.s. If creating that model wrong/there's a better way, please let me know. I'm a little unsure if thats the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use data classes for the models. Also, use kotlin jacksonObjectMapper() instead of ObjectMapper(). Standard ObjectMapper will not work in Kotlin. Or inject ObjectMapper from Spring context. Add `"com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin"` in your dependencies.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class MyModel (
val id : String,
val s3FilePath : String
)

import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue
class FirstMessage {
fun create(newMessage: String) : String {

    val parsedMap : MyModel = jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(newMessage)

    return jacksonObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(parsedMap)
}
}

class FirstMessageTest {

@Test
fun incompleteDataReturnsException() {
    val input = """{"missing": "parts"}"""

   assertThrows (MissingKotlinParameterException::class.java
{FirstMessage().create(input)} // Will make some assertion here here
}

@Test
fun `Should parse`() {
    val input = """{"id":"id",
        "missing": "parts",
        "s3FilePath":"somePath"}"""

    FirstMessage().create(input) // Will make some assertion here here
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks - and how can I also validate against, empty strings? For example, thow an error is `s3FilePath` is `""`?

Comment: In Spring application you can simply add annotations for fields - @NotEmpty, and in the service #@Validated on class and #@Valid in the method, for example, fun save(#@Valid myclass: Myclass). But for your tests, I think this will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063892/validating-json-using-constraints-annotations-is-not-working

Comment: I didn't realize that Kotlin required a different object for mapping; I was running into a simple deserialization issue using `ObjectMapper` in Kotlin that had me scratching my head for hours yesterday.  Your answer helped me solve that particular issue... tyvm!

Comment: @MassDotNet Yes, this is one of the things I always forget about when I start coding in Kotlin after Java.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correct, you just want to check if your required properties are set. So I would suggest checking for that properties after you parsed the string with something like this:

```
class FirstMessage {
    fun create(newMessage: String) : String {

        val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()

        // validation 1: your input is valid JSON
        val parsedMap : MyModel = objectMapper.readValue(newMessage, MyModel::class.java) 

        // validation 2: check that your properties are set
        if(parsedMap.id.isNullOrEmpty() || 
           parsedMap.s3FilePath.isNullOrEmpty())
        {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input")
        }

        val result = MyModel()
        result.id = parsedMap.id
        result.s3FilePath = parsedMap.s3FilePath

        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(result)
    }
}
```

Depending of the scope, a nicer solution would be a new annotation like `@NotEmpty` that you set on the properties of your target class that are required and have a generic parser function which validates all the annotated fields on your parsed object and throws a better exception which says exactly which fields are missing.